# dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile error

Tags: apt, 20.04, dpkg

While installing any package in ubuntu it stops in the unpacking step showing this message

```
Preparing to unpack .../00-linux-modules-5.4.0-149-generic_5.4.0-149.166_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.4.0-149-generic (5.4.0-149.166) over (5.4.0-149.166) ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 wait for dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile subprocess failed: No child processes

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2
```

It's not specific to "linux-modules-5.4.0-149-generic" it's happening for anything I try to install for example:

```
Preparing to unpack .../00-autopoint_0.19.8.1-10build1_all.deb ...
Unpacking autopoint (0.19.8.1-10build1) over (0.19.8.1-10build1) ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 wait for dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile subprocess failed: No child processes
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```